# sequelize add method many to many doesnt work

Tags: sequelize.js

I have

```
Order.belongsToMany(Product, { through: 'OrderProducts'});
Product.belongsToMany(Order, { through: 'OrderProducts' });
```

I want to add products to my currentorder

```
let newOrder = null
        
        const myuser = await User.findByPk('4455a5b1-08bf-4565-9a82-862cc5fdbd3c')
       


        const currentOrder = await Order.findOrCreate({ where : { UserId : '4455a5b1-08bf-4565-9a82-862cc5fdbd3c',onay : false, } })
       
        const productId = '5ba82614-7856-43ee-8262-0859081786ae'
        const adet = 5
        let foundProduct = await Product.findByPk(productId)

        let a = await currentOrder.addOrderProducts(foundProduct)
```

when I do this I get following error

I tried several methods set get vs. it doesnt work

```
TypeError: currentOrder.addOrderProducts is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot! it worked!

```
const order = await Order.create({UserId: 'e9213d32-a32e-46f5-a085-6b513129fce1'})
const product = await Product.create({ productName: 'uçan halı', productDescription: 'halı bildiğin uçuyor..', price: 4000 })

await order.addProduct(product)
```